# How to set relative path to executive script

Tags: python

I want to set relative path to folder with my executive script that will works from any machine without hardcoding absolute path to file.
So far I have following:

```
import os
path_to_folder = os.path.realpath('.')
```

When I run my script from `PyCharm` calling `print(path_to_folder)` return correct path

`C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Project\Script\`

But if I try to call it from `cmd` like `python3.4 C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Project\Script\my_script.py` I get just

`C:\Users\Me\`

What is the more reliable way to set relative path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to use [Pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

```
# get sibling file
sib = Path(__file__).with_name(same_level_file)

# get parent
par = Path(__file__).parent

# file in sibling parent
sib2 = Path(__file__).parent.with_name(parent_folder).joinpath(file2)
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without Pathlib just using the __file__ variable that Python defines every module.

In the parent script itself:

```
from os.path import dirname, abspath
path_to_folder = abspath(dirname(__file__))
print(path_to_folder)
```

Or more generally if you just want to know where a module is located, you can just do:

```
from os.path import dirname, abspath
import mymodule
path_to_folder = abspath(dirname(mymodule.__file__))
print(path_to_folder)
```